# How to implement cheaper bank account recurrent debits in my web app?

Tags: transactions, payment-processing, recurring-billing

I want to make recurrent charges to my customer`s bank account from my app, without any need for interaction on his side.

Currently, I am considering two options with Stripe.

First is ACH Credit with a $1 fee per transaction, which is good, but it is push-based and I need customer to take action to fund some kind of virtual account, every time, which I can charge later:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'customer' => 'cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs',
  'source' => 'src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0',
]);
```

Second is ACH Direct Debit which allows me to recurrently debit directly my customer`s bank account without any interaction on his side, but fees can reach $5 per transaction:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => 1500,
  'currency' => 'bgn',
  'customer' => 'cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs',
]);
```

There are companies that charge, for example, $2 per transaction, what services do they use, or do they use a different approach?